# Syntax error MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Есть вот такая запись: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему то MySql Workbench отказывается воспринимать это: `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` с ошибкой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Код лучше не прикреплять скринами.

Comment: Да у меня не получается его сделать по нормально как на скрине, вставляю его как код, а оно всё равно после 1й строки сбивается.

Comment: возможно вы хотели написать `\`FIELD_TIMESTAMP\` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?  или  `\`FIELD_TIMESTAMP\` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()`

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы при вставке значения или его обновлении там было именно число с начала UNIX времени(настоящее время). Проблема в том, что методы не работают, ошибку программа выдаёт (на скрине).

Comment: *Мне нужно, чтобы* Если не хотите читать документацию (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html), то хотя бы слушайте умные советы. `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` либо `DEFAULT 0` либо отсутствие `DEFAULT` - это **исчерпывающий** список вариантов. И @АлексейШиманский указал тот вариант, который решает требуемую задачу.

Comment: Допустим вариант `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` устраняет ошибку, на выходе даётся полная дата, но как это перевести в long число или такого нет и это надо делать программно?

Comment: *как это перевести в long число* А вот тут как раз и нужна `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`. И в MySQL нет типа long - штамп времени в зависимости от значения вернётся как INTEGER либо как DECIMAL. Впрочем, всё это и многие прочие подробности есть в документации.

Comment: Я же пишу что в это и проблема! У меня программа на этот метод ругается `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`...

Comment: Ох ты ж ё-о-о... В списке полей вывода надо применять функцию!!! а не в DDL таблицы.

Comment: Мда, как же я сейчас затупил, аж стыдно,